# A large Oracle database with no foreign keys

Tags: database-design, oracle

I am struggling to understand the design of an Oracle database that I have been working with for the past 9 months. The database is for our business management system and I work with it mostly for reporting and data warehousing.

The database has just over 5,000 tables (not all of them are being used) and so when I started working with it I had trouble understanding the relationship between different tables and finding the ones that were important to me. To make it worse, there are no foreign key relationships. At least, I'm yet to see one after 9 months. Additionally, the same fields are repeated in more than one table. For example, both the customer order line table and the customer invoice table have the fields order, line, and release and these fields are part of the primary key in both cases. Couldn't this have been managed by a relationship? I guess the one plus side to that is that I can query for the invoice information using the customer order data without using any joins.

I have also been recently been reviewing the functionality in some of the packages because we want to use some of the procedures for some custom tasks that we want to add. While reviewing, I found that cascade updates and default values are being managed in pl/sql code. Again, this can be done just by defining it as a part of the schema, but I even struggle to call it a *cascade update* because in the particular case I am referring to, it wouldn't be even be required if they didn't have repeated information in different tables. As for the default values, the UI for the system allows certain users to change default values and this approach avoids having to alter the table.

Now, this is from a large, successful vendor with many customers. I struggle to understand why these choose this design. I didn't go to school for computer science and I don't have enough experience to pass strong judgement on their design, so I keep telling myself that this is just some esoteric technique that I haven't been made privy to. I would really love to understand, why?

**Edit:**

Just to clarify my comment above about cascade update. It's a bad practice and I don't think Oracle even has cascade update. But I didn't mean a cascade update in the true sense of the word. It was the update of duplicate information across multiple tables.

I must say though, despite the lack referential constraints, the data integrity of the application is robust and trustworthy (they have a ton of pl/sql code to ensure this). I mean these guys aren't amateurs (setting aside what most would call bad design). This I was just curious to know if there was something I was missing. But as people it the comments have stated, I may never know why they did what they did and how decisions made 20 years ago are affecting their architecture now. All I know is that they have a product that works and sells.

Comment: Any chance you can run like hell?

Comment: On a more serious note, there isn't any possible way this question is answerable without knowing something more about the vendor or the table design.

Comment: I wish I could tell you more. I'm not sure what to say. This is my first experience I have working with a *serious* database. Before this, I had only made Microsoft Access databases with forms on top of them. I just don't have the DBA vernacular to concisely explain the design -- especially one that I can't make sense of.

Comment: And I kind of don't want to say the vendor name.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an ERP system like (for example) Microsoft's Navision. They have the nice option to change the primary key (No.) of the product data which then is cascaded through all tables that reference those products. (Which can be millions of rows for products that are old and have a lot of orders, invoices etc). Products like this have a lot of 'history', decisions made sometimes 25 years ago and just nobody ever wanted to change that. Also some older versions really don't have any other option for external access but directly query the database.

Comment: For the 'repetition' of information: Some information has to be stored as is at a given point in time to make sure that you can exactly reproduce invoices and tax related data many years later. Other 'options' of the design are meant to allow users to customize features since for such systems every customer has a slightly different workflow. A wholesale company works different from a retailer and sales companies different from manufacturing companies.

Comment: If Thorsten is right. If problem is ERP-like db design, there's nothing to understand. It could be.someone's design that was excelent at managing ERP solutions but just ignorant at RMDB models. In many situations the migration ends being a mere copy file-table. 5000 tables... I would seriously think on what Robert Harvey has told: *any chance you can run like hell?*

Comment: I am wonderkng that you query the database directly. You have an Oracle Db with 5000+ tables. this sounds like a full sized ERP or PIM and so on. I wondering there is no reporting tool/generator. If we are talking about a paid solution with a stable base there is just one thing i could imagine: Your boss dont want to îspend money for the reporting tool. Else there should be an api or a report generator that should fit your needs.

Comment: @thorstenmüller thanks for the feedback. It is an ERP system. Your comment about the repeated information makes a lot of sense as well. We wouldn't want, for example, the address on the invoice to change when the customer changes their location at some later date. I would encourage you to post your comments as the answer.

Comment: Also, I was looking at a description of the product online, and it the description it is praised for being flexible, reconfigurable, and easy to upgrade. That is pretty much inline with what thorstenmüller said about different customers having different workflows and what @Laiv said about migration.

Comment: @Michael they do have some reporting solutions out of the box, but it really does not even come close to what we need. Every company operates differently and I wouldn't expect that to have generic reports that work for our business processes out of the box. And when I say reporting, I'm not talking about invoices and other transactional or paginated reports. They have that taken care of. I'm talking about larger business wide metrics, company performance, and insight into company operations.

Comment: As Robert said, there's no way we can tell what the designers of this system were thinking when they chose to do it this way (or if they even chose it consciously).

Comment: In our company, at least in a legacy part of the databases we don't use foreign keys because (as a legend from old times says) 
foreign keys architecture is too rigid. By the way, you can "google://foreign keys evil" there are plenty flame wars/blog posts on this theme

Comment: It could be worse.  My first programming job was for a telco whose customer and sales commission database lacked *primary* keys.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, that's just insane. I guess it could be worse.

Comment: You need to clarify whether or not there are undeclared foreign keys.  An undeclared foreign key is a column (or set of columns) that function like a foreign key, but there is no constraint in the database to indicate this.  You need to be an achaeologist to figure this one out.  My first choice would be to run like hell.

Comment: Yes, there are undeclared foreign keys. But there's other stuff too that I have no words for ... You have no idea how much time I wasted hunting down *reliable* relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are digging around in the implementation details of a large product that (probably) is designed to be used via GUI's and APIs.

In your position, I would be asking myself why I was doing this.  Probably you would be better off not >>trying<< to understand.  If you really need to know this kind of thing, then you are probably trying to use the product the wrong way ... or it is not suitable for your needs.

---

> ...  I keep telling myself that this is just some esoteric technique that I haven't been made privy to. I would really love to understand, why?

Well, yea, that is possible.  It could also just be the result of poor design, or of the accretion of features.

Anyhow, I think your best bet would be to ask the vendor for more information. The vendor is under no obligation to explain to you these things, but they may be able to help anyway.

Note that some representative of your organization may well have signed an agreement with the vendor that >>forbids<< reverse engineering of the product.  You might want to check that, if you / your management haven't already done so.

Comment: i tend to agree with you to some degree but not entirely. The reason why I noticed what I found to be a strange design in the first place, is because I am writing queries for reporting purposes and so that we can have insight into our business performance. Therefore, I needed to know what tables I need to be querying against. And the reason why I was looking at their procedures is because they allow us to build in custom functionality, which we are taking advantage of. In doing so, I would like to use their procedures where applicable.

Comment: That was in response to the first part of your answer. The part before the edit.

Comment: *"The reason why I noticed what I found to be a strange design in the first place, is because I am writing queries for reporting purpose"* - Is that how the product is >designed< to be used?  Does the vendor documentation say "query the database directly"?  I suspect not.  Therefore my suggestion that you are using it the wrong way and/or it is the wrong product.

Comment: Actually, we are allowed to query the database directly. We can pretty much do whatever we want as long as we do not modify what they have done. There are other customers that we are in contact with who also do the same. The pre-built reports do not satisfy our needs, neither could we really expect it to for reporting purposes. As a business we need to be able to *ask* any question that our data can provide and no one knows our processes like we do. But I think we are beginning to stray a little here.

Comment: *Probably you would be better off not >>trying<< to understand*  Oh, yeah. Once I quit struggling to understand bewildering aspects of our code design it got easier to deal with. Fewer headaches and less frustration, et cetera really did improve my ability to work with the code. Over time, I found some of it is quite impressive. Eventually you realize one cannot explain stupid. So once you suspect there is no pony under that pile of shit you just quit trying altogether and refactor and re-code as time and opportunity allow. And find peace through acceptance of the rest.